# Java CompletableFutures: is it ever a acceptable to not join/get?

Tags: java, completable-future

Is it ever correct to not return or join on a CompletableFuture?

That is, is this code ever correct?

```
void noJoin() {
   CompletableFuture<Void> cfa = CompletableFuture
                                   .supplyAsync(() -> "a")
                                   .thenAccept(this::someSideEffect);

   CompletableFuture<Void> cfb = CompletableFuture
                                   .supplyAsync(() -> "b")
                                   .thenAccept(this::someSideEffect);
}
```

In the above code, we never know if the Futures complete successfully, or at all. (And I don't even know that the Futures created in noJoin are not eligible for garbage collection; but presumably the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() holds onto those references?)

In any case, if it truly doesn't matter to our program whether or not those Futures succeed, a better implementation of `noJoin` is just a no-op:

```
void noJoin() {}
```

If on the other hand, it does matter, we need to either join on or return *both* Futures, by composing them (either serially with thenCompose, or in parallel with thenCombine or allOf) and then join the composed Future or return it to our caller.

By joining, we block and throw an exception if either Future is exceptional; or better, by returning a Future, we remain asynchronous while ensuring that our caller gets a Future that holds any exceptional result:

```
Future<Void> returnBothAsync() {

       CompletableFuture<Void> cfa = CompletableFuture
                                       .supplyAsync(() -> "a")
                                       .thenAccept(this::someSideEffect);

       CompletableFuture<Void> cfb = CompletableFuture
                                       .supplyAsync(() -> "b")
                                       .thenAccept(this::someSideEffect);

       return CompletableFuture.allOf(cfa, cfb);
}
```

or

```
void joinBothBlocking() {

       CompletableFuture<Void> cfa = CompletableFuture
                                       .supplyAsync(() -> "a")
                                       .thenAccept(this::someSideEffect);

       CompletableFuture<Void> cfb = CompletableFuture
                                       .supplyAsync(() -> "b")
                                       .thenAccept(this::someSideEffect);

       CompletableFuture.allOf(cfa, cfb).get(50L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I think this is true even if we arrange to handle all exceptions:

```
void noJoin() {
   CompletableFuture<Void> cfa = CompletableFuture
                                   .supplyAsync(() -> "a")
                                   .thenAccept(this::someSideEffect)
                                   .exceptionally(e -> {
                                         Logger.log(e);
                                         return DEFAULT;
                                   });

   CompletableFuture<Void> cfb = CompletableFuture
                                   .supplyAsync(() -> "b")
                                   .thenAccept(this::someSideEffect);
}
```

because even if the exceptional are handled / "can't happen", we still don't know if the Future ever completed at all.

Or am I wrong, and there are cases where code like that in `noJoin` is correct?

Comment: Are you essentially looking for examples/cases where it's not correct to discard a completablefuture instance?

Comment: You know that the asynchronous operation completed when `this::someSideEffect` has produced its side effect.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer to your question. It probably depends on the exact use case to be able to tell how to handle `CompletableFuture` and their results.

If you choose to not wait for the results of the `CompletableFuture`s, you will likely have to make sure that the used executor finishes all tasks. In your case the used executor is [ForkJoinPool.commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) whose documentation says:

> [...] However this pool and any ongoing processing are automatically terminated upon program System.exit(int). Any program that relies on asynchronous task processing to complete before program termination should invoke commonPool().awaitQuiescence, before exit.